# Simple multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I try to implement a function which prints each thread number . For example thread 0 prints 0 thread 1 prints 1 and so on , but not in this expected order.

What I have been trying so far is this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *foo(void *arg){
    int *myid = (int*) arg;
    printf("Hello from thread %d\n",*myid);
    return NULL;
}
int main(void){
   pthread_t tid[4];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,(void*) foo, &i);
  
   }
   for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

However this prints almost everytime Hello from thread 0 four times. How can I modify this code so each thread gets printed correctly?

Comment: Don't return `NULL` from thread function, use `pthread_exit`

Comment: Also, do check the return value of `pthread_create`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: You're passing the address of the loop index `i` to `foo`.  What happens if, for example, none of the threads actually start `foo` until *after* the loop has completed?

Comment: And always read the compiler warnings: `(void*) foo` is wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/aGYYTqq36 
Just remove the cast.

Comment: @kiner_shah Is there any reason to use `pthread_exit(NULL);` over `return NULL;`? "_Performing a `return` from the start function of any thread other than the main thread results in an implicit call to `pthread_exit()`, using the function's return value as the thread's exit status._"

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I would never use return - there must be some reason why `pthread_exit` is explicitly defined in the pthreads library, otherwise there is no point of that function being there. Also what is the source of that quote you mentioned?

Comment: @kiner_shah Given that the man page says that `return x;` results in `pthread_exit(x);` I don't think there is a difference at all. As for _why_ `pthread_exit` is exposed to users in pthreads, I don't know. The standard C threads `thrd_exit` function doesn't seem to give the users the same freedom.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I don't see man page mentioning this explicitly anywhere: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html. If the man page states "return NULL is equivalent to pthread_exit(NULL)" explicitly, then I will accept :-)

Comment: @kiner_shah Oh, it's in the Notes: "_Performing a `return` from the start function of any thread other than the main thread results in an implicit call to `pthread_exit()`, **using the function's return value** as the thread's exit status._"

Comment: @kiner_shah `pthread_exit()` helps leaving the thread from a deeper function call (not the top thread function). It's the same as `exit()` from anywhere vs `return` in `main()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yeah you are right, I found it in 5.10 (in the man pages git repo). But I wonder why it was removed in 5.13.

Comment: @kiner_shah It isn't removed in 5.13. It's still there down in the Notes section.

Comment: @prog-fh, yes I got it. So, it's way different than standard return, it's like exit(), but like call that function from anywhere within that thread and the thread can be exit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, it's really there, weird I somehow missed that.

Comment: @kiner_shah it's about your remark « otherwise there is no point of that function being there ». If return was the only option to leave the thread, then we could not decide to leave this thread from another function called by this thread (I 'm not saying I would do that but the possibility exists with `pthread_exit()`).

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in the address of `i` to each of the threads, so they each read the current state of `i` (and without synchronization, so the results are unpredictable if not undefined).

Instead, you need to pass a pointer to thread-specific data (that has a lifetime at least as long as the thread). For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *foo(void *arg){
    int *myid = (int*) arg;
    printf("Hello from thread %d\n",*myid);
    return NULL;
}
int main(void){
   pthread_t tid[4];
   int ids[4];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       ids[i] = i;
       pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,(void*) foo, &ids[i]);
  
   }
   for(i=0;i<4;i++){
       pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend that you check the return value of `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic situation where all the threads share the same data, but should not.

Here you pass `&i` to each thread, thus all of them refer to the same location in memory: the only one where the single variable `i` is stored.
You need to pass a *value* but in the pthread API it is not easy since a pointer (`void *`) is expected.

A strategy is to prepare beforehand an array with a distinct element for each thread and pass the address of the nth element to the nth thread.

Another strategy is to dynamically allocate a new piece of information (an `int` here) at each iteration of the loop, initialise it (with a counter for example) and pass this address to the thread.
Then the thread will have to `free()` its own piece of information before it leaves.
This strategy is more heavyweight than the previous.

Note that sometimes we see in code an ugly shortcut, just to pass a single `int`.
At the call site you pass `(void *)(intptr_t)i` and in the thread you get back `(int)(intptr_t)arg`.
The trick is that we consider the pointer as a very big integer, thus we convert back and forth.
I would not recommand that for some serious code, only for a quick experiment.

Comment: It makes sense , thanks !